# Pythagoras Theorem in Triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles

The question is:

> In a triangle  $\triangle ABC$, angle $\angle B = 90^\circ$ and $M$ is the mid-point of $BC$. Prove that $|AC|^2 = |AM|^2 + 3|BM|^2$.

[image: Triangles]

Please help me. I have tried various ways but can't figure out a way.

Thanks.

Comment: I should try this approach on my taxes:  Dear IRS: I looked at your forms. I tried to fill them out but I couldn't figure out a way. Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Pythagoras' Theorem twice and substitute.

You know from Pythagoras that $AC^2 = AB^2 + BC^2$.

Since $M$ is the mid-point of [BC], $$BC = 2BM, \Longrightarrow BC^2 = 4BM^2$$
Also using Pythagoras on triangle $ABM$ that $$AM^2 = AB^2 + BM^2$$
ie $$AB^2 = AM^2 - BM^2$$

Sub everything in the first equation to get:$$AC^2 =\underbrace{AM^2 - BM^2}_{=AB^2} +  \underbrace{4BM^2}_{=BC^2} $$
$$\Longrightarrow AC^2 = AM^2 + 3BM^2$$

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the triangle $\triangle ABM$ and get $|AB|^2$ from $|AM|^2$ and $|BM|^2$. Then use $|AB|^2$ and $|AC|^2 = (2|BM|)^2$ to get $|AC|^2$.

**Edit:** Here it is:

Note that $|AB|^2 + |BM|^2 = |AM|^2$, so $|AB|^2 = |AM|^2 - |BM|^2$.

Now, we see that

\begin{align*}
|AC|^2 &= |AB|^2 + |BC|^2 = (|AM|^2 - |BM|^2) + (2|BM|)^2 \\
&= |AM|^2 - |BM|^2 + 4|BM|^2 = |AM|^2 + 3|BM|^2.
\end{align*}

Comment: So, I got $|BM|^2 = |AM|^2 - |AB|^2$ .And the final answer which I get is $|AC|^2 = 2|AM|^2 - |AB|^2$,which is wrong...

Comment: I said to get $|AB|^2$ from the other two, not $|BM|^2$. Here, I've edited my answer. I hope it helps you.